# VSCode language identifier doesn't work for Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-blade

VS Code automatically does not define `.blade.php` files. That is, I should manually switch the mode through the "Select Language Mode" button in the lower right corner or through hot keys (Ctrl + K + M) so that the file is identified as `.blade.php` and then the code is highlighted.

[image]

Otherwise, the file is identified simply as `.php`.

I have several extensions, including "Laravel Blade Snippets" and "Laravel Blade Spacer":

[image]

What needs to be done so that VS Code automatically recognizes `.blade.php` files?

Maybe it's about the Settings (JSON)?
[image]

Comment: In my VSCode settings, I have `"files.associations": {"blade": "html", ".blade.php": "html"}`, and for some reason, my `.blade.php` files are recognized as `Blade` in the bottom left. If you do `CTRL + SHIFT + P` (or `CMD + SHIFT + P`), then type `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`, you might see something similar there.

Comment: @Tim Lewis: In my Settings (JSON) file was the following: `Files.associations": {{ "*.php": "PHP"
}`, I added two lines: `Files.associations": {{ "*.php": "PHP", "Blade": "html", ".blade.php": "html"
}`.
Nothing changed.

Comment: @Tim Lewis: thanks a lot, you pointed me in the right direction. Did this:
`Files.associations": {{ "*.php": "PHP", "*.blade.php": "blade" }`
Now everything works.

Comment: Nice! I knew that would be the right track, but I'm honestly not sure why mine is different but works the same as yours does... I have the same extension and everything, but a different association in `settings.json`; how bizarre. But regardless, glad you were able to get it working 

Answer (score 1):

In file `settings.json` (to open it press Ctrl + Shift + P and type "Settings (JSON)")
I added the line `"*.blade.php": "blade"` in file association part.

As a result (in my case):

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.php": "php",
    "*.blade.php": "blade"
}
```

Now files with extension `blade.php` are recognized and treated as Blade code.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following extensions:

1. [Laravel Extra Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amiralizadeh9480.laravel-extra-intellisense)
2. [Laravel intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mohamedbenhida.laravel-intellisense)
3. [vscode-icons](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue after installing **"Laravel Blade Snippets"** vscode extension by **Winnie Lin** the problem was solved.